# Parse, JS Updates in Real Time

Tags: parse-platform

I have the following code, where I have a myBool (a boolean) in my Data Browser initially set to false, 
however sometime while I'm still viewing my page I have code set to turn it to true.
How can I make a real time update that will automatically hide my #div when myBool turns to true?

```
var myBool = currentUser.get("myBool");
    if(myBool) {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
```

I did some research and found that the `Parse.Cloud.afterSave()` function may be useful, but I don't see how it will update the content automatically?

Hope I've been clear!

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Possibly something like this in my `main.js`?

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("setBool", function() {

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo('myBool', true);

        Parse.Push.send({
          where: query, 
        }, {
          success: function() {
            $('#div').hide();
          },
          error: function(error) {
            $('#div').show();
          }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with your afterSave function is that your calling it for a function rather than a class.

AfterSave is called after an object from a certain class is saved. If your bool

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.Installation, function(request) {
    // Send push here, use request to target correct user
});
```

Additionally your push listener should be the one modifying the divs, not the CloudCode.